# Error while creating a list from a template

Tags: sharepoint-online

One of my lists reachs 5000 elements, and can't accept more. I try to archive it. I created a template, including content.

Then, I create a new list on this template, I try it several times, on several comptures, on several internet connection, but every time :
"Something went wrong.
This is a temporary issue, so try again in a few minutes.
Technical details :
Ref A: 53254DDB5FC74C18ACD0F0C35D14AEDF Ref B: LON21EDGE1011 Ref C: 2018-10-04T07:38:43Z"

Is there an other way to do it ? How can I manage to succeed this operation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, works with IE BUT with the same error message.
Edge and Chrome : error, with maximum 80% of content back, and list I can't open.